# Configuring NGINX with SSL and Node.js on CENTOS 6 in EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ssl, node.js

I'm trying to deploy a Node.js web-app on a Centos EC2 instance with an elastic IP.
The SSL certificate is already setup and properly configured.
I would like to allow only https connection to my app, but I get the following error:

> [error] 2471#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream.

here is my NGINX(v 1.6.1) config file:

```
server {
listen      80 default;
server_name example.com www.example.com;
## redirect http to https ##
rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
listen       443 ssl;
server_name  example.com www.example.com;
root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
client_max_body_size 20M;

 if ($host = 'www.example.com' ) {
 rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://example.com/$1  permanent;
  }

ssl_certificate      /etc/ssh/ssl-bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssh/com.key;
ssl_session_timeout  5m;
ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

## Node.js specific##
location / {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
}
}
```

Comment: are you sure your node.js app is running on port 3000?

Comment: Indeed, with [Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) running on background, apparently everything seemed working well, instead there was nothing for NGINX to forward.The above configuration is correct.

Comment: can you paste the output of `netstat -tlupn | grep 3000`

Comment: `tcp   0  0  0.0.0.0:3000     0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      3858/node` fixing some app code issues with the new server now the website is up an running on https. Thx Mike